# Order function doesn't do anything in PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter as a framework.
Now I want to order a list but it doesn't react on DESC or ASC.

My code is:

```
function get_community($limit, $smallicon = false) {
        $this->db->select('user_to_designment.user_id, count(user_to_designment.user_id) as designment_joined, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.middle_name, user_profiles.last_name');
        $this->db->from('user_to_designment');
        $this->db->join('user_to_user_profile', 'user_to_designment.user_id = user_to_user_profile.user_id');
        $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'user_to_user_profile.profile_id = user_profiles.profile_id');
        $this->db->group_by('user_id');
        $this->db->order_by('designment_joined', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $communitys = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        foreach ($communitys as &$community) {
            if($smallicon){
                $community['image'] = self::get_small_user_icon_by_id($community['user_id']);
            }else{
                $community['image'] = self::get_big_user_icon_by_id($community['user_id']);
            }
        }

        return $communitys;
    }
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` with `GROUP BY` won't work. You may need to use a sub query with `ORDER BY`  and apply `GROUP BY`  on outer select query.

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` **should** work together. Have you tried placing the order by before group by?

Comment: If you run the SQL query directly, without php etc, do you get the correct order or not?

Comment: @SankarV look at what budwiser said

Comment: @budwiser did not work

Comment: @jarlh i dont know how to do this.

Comment: @budwiser - i think it won't work in mysql. Please google it. As mentioned earlier you may need to use a sub query with ORDER BY and apply GROUP BY on outer select query.

Comment: @ManuelSterk - Did you research on this? Did you find any solution other than using a sub query with ORDER BY and applying GROUP BY on outer select query.

Comment: @SankarV It absolutely works in MySQL. There are plenty of examples even here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @budwiser Please check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html : **_...the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses..._** Also if you know the answer, then please help `Manuel Sterk` by answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**designment_joined** is a **count(user_to_designment.user_id)** which will give the same value. So you can not see the difference. Try the query directly in PHPMyAdmin and see the result. Also try to change the field name in orderby clause and check.

eg :

Replace `$this->db->order_by('designment_joined', 'desc');` with `$this->db->order_by('user_to_designment.user_id', 'desc');` and check.

**Updated Code:**

```
$this->db->select('user_to_designment.user_id, count(user_to_designment.user_id) as designment_joined, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.middle_name, user_profiles.last_name');
        $this->db->from('user_to_designment');
        $this->db->join('user_to_user_profile', 'user_to_designment.user_id = user_to_user_profile.user_id');
        $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'user_to_user_profile.profile_id = user_profiles.profile_id');
        $this->db->order_by('user_to_designment.user_id', 'desc');
        $this->db->limit($limit);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. But i did not work. i replaced it but i will still show the same

Comment: did you tried the query directly in PHPMyAdmin? also try to replace with the updated code in the my post

Comment: Hey i tried it in phpmyadmin and it worked, but your php update doesnt work for me.

Comment: If still not working, then replace **$this->db->order_by** with **$this->db->orderby** and check. **$this->db->orderby** is a old method. Probably it will not work. But give a try.

Comment: Please share the query you have tried in PHPMyAdmin. We can create format from the query

Comment: Hey, thank for your help i had to add some javascript to make it fully working! thanks a lot